# Comprehensive synchronization - backup system

Tags: backup, sync

Does somebody know a synchronization system with file version control?

I have about 3-5 GB of data which I want to synchronize with another storage (directory). Both directory should store the last versions of files. So if any changes occur in one directory, they must be reflected into another one and vice verse. Also all changes ( not matter how large they were: remove of 1GB file or a simple text line addition) should be stored. Of course, rollback should be available.

To make a certain notion of what I am talking about here it is some examples.

1. **Dropbox** - system make a synchronization of local storage and remote. It has a backup and version control feature. Very good system I like it, I use it, but it only works for local directory and for remote Dropbox storage. However I need to use it for local data and more flexible job configuration.
2. **VSC** (mercurial, git, svn, ....) - synchronization of repositories of text files. Very comprehensive systems, I use them for my documents, there were no occurrences when I could not find something in their capabilities ever. But how I have said it is only for text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use git for this. Follow [this guide](http://michael.otacoo.com/linux-2/setting-a-git-server-with-dropbox/), but put your repo somewhere else (NOT the place you want to sync with!) and then `git init` the two syncing places, and connect them to the repo you made by adding remotes. Done! You can now use Git to sync your two places by adding, committing, pushing and pulling.

Comment: OK, I thought about that. But I don't know can git restore my files. For example, I have two directory on my computer which I want to synchronize, then I have removed a 287MB pdf from both of them ( I suppose that I don't need it). But suddenly I have realized that I need it. Can I restore it with git?

Comment: Well if you have not already pushed the changes to the main repo, yes, you can git pull. If you have, though, you're stuffed. You might be able to rebase it back, but I am not sure...

Comment: I am not either ))

Comment: You could always never delete the file from the server, if you don't mind (disk space)